# PETSC Build Error : C compiler does not work

Tags: cygwin, petsc

I am trying to install PETSc on Cygwin terminal by invoking following command..

```
./configure --with-cc='win32fe cl'  --with-fc='win32fe ifort' --with-cxx='win32fe cl' --download-fblaslapack
```

and

```
/configure --with-cc=cl --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-fblaslapack --download-mpich
```

It shoots me below error:

```
C compiler you provided with -with-cc=win32fe cl does not work
C compiler you provided with -with-cc=cl does not work
```

I'm new to Unix platform so please help me on this.

Comment: A similar problem: ./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-mpich --download-fblaslapack
             Configuring PETSc to compile on your system
TESTING: checkCCompiler from config.setCompilers(config/BuildSystem/config/setCompilers.py:620)                                               UNABLE to CONFIGURE with GIVEN OPTIONS    (see configure.log for details):
C compiler you provided with -with-cc=gcc does not work.
Cannot compile C with gcc.
 **But let me assure you that gcc works fine. It tests out AOK on helloWorld.cpp.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
./configure --with-cc="win32fe\ cl"  --with-fc="win32fe\ ifort" --with-cxx="win32fe\ cl" --download-fblaslapack
```

Note the backslashes added before the whitespaces to escape them.

Comment: ./configure --with-cc=gcc --with-cxx=g++ --with-fc=gfortran --download-mpich --download-fblaslapack does not have any whitespaces to escape, but the error is still the same. This is with a fully functional mingw-gcc installation 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Is necessary use VStudio prompt (or other C compiler provider) to run CygWin64.

Have to follow the instructions.